# jenkins selenium grid v2 confiduration

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, jenkins-plugins

I need a help with configuration and updating jenkins selenium plugin.
I can configure selenium hub and nodes outside of jenkins and run tests from maven so selenium itself is not a problem.

1 problem: jenkins selenium plugin already defines default node with list of available browsers (5 firefox, 5 chromes, 2 IE). I would like all my test to be run on other machine than jenkins. so I was able to point my remote node to jenkins machine and it is registered there. my question is how I remove default node browser configuration ???

2 problem: how can I update to latest selenium-server-standalone version (which currently is 2.24.1). right now I can see jenkins is using 2.15.0. I tried to add jar in ...jenkins/plugins/selenium/WEB-INF/lib and update license.xml but after I restarted jenkins it still uses older version

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer on you second question. To update selenium-server-standalone version you must perform the following steps:

1) Download the latest version of selenium-server-standalone
2) Put it in to YourJenkinsHomeDirectory/plugins/selenium/WEB-INF/lib
3) Edit licenses.xml file in YourJenkinsHomeDirectory/plugins/selenium/WEB-INF

Edit following (Edit the text highlighted in bold. Paste the value of the version of your selenium-server-standalone):

l:dependency name='Unnamed - org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server-standalone:pom:**2.39.0**' groupId='org.seleniumhq.selenium' artifactId='selenium-server-standalone' version='**2.39.0**'

Save file

4) Go to YourJenkinsHomeDirectory/Home/plugins/selenium/META-INF/maven/org.jenkins-ci.plugins/selenium

5) Edit pom.xml

Than find next:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-server-standalone</artifactId>
      <version>2.39.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>2.39.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

And edit `<version>2.39.0</version>` in both block. Paste the value of the version of your selenium-server-standalone

Save file

6) Restart your Jenkins (simply go to this `http://your-jenkins-url/restart`) as default the url is: `http://localhost:8080`. Now Jenkins should restart

7)Go to your Selenium Grid hub `http://localhost:4444/grid/console`

8)Now you should see your updated version

Good luck :)

Comment: thanks, I asked this question a year ago but :) it is never late for a help